# How to print unique name in UNIX using command

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, passwd

I want help to print only one name from my /etc/passwd file. 
For example, if there are two entries named "avi" and "avig", then how should I print only "avi"? I have tried cut, unique command but am not getting proper output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to anchor the string you're searching for. Try `egrep '^avi:' /etc/passwd`.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get just the entry for a given user from your `passwd` you should just use the `getent` command like

```
getent passwd avi
```

otherwise, you'll just need to make sure your regex/pattern is specific enough to only match what you want.

If your `grep` supports it you can tell `grep` to only match your pattern as the whole word like

```
grep -w ^avi /etc/passwd
```

works with GNU and BSD greps